# Best way to crawl/extract data from multiple websites

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I am new to the mentioned problem and just started learning about scraping and crawling the websites.

I came to know about python BeautifulSoup4 that works really great for the extraction of data from a website. My main is problem is to handle a large number of sites.

For example more than 10000 different websites.
As far as I know and studied till now, that the crawling is done when we tell the program about the classes of different tags such as

```
<h3 class="this">Hello World </h3>
```

so for extracting it from a page.
The python scrapy program will look like this.

```
    url = 'http://www.anyurl.com'
    source = requests.get(url)
    plain_text = source.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text,"html.parser")
        h3_text = soup.find('h3', {'class':'this'}) 
        print(h3_text.text)
```

From the above example, it is clear that we have a site in which there is h3 tag having a class "this".

Now for more than 10000 different websites, having different classes and structures. What is the best way to do that? I am trying to develop a type of search engine just like "Google" but with some specific amount of websites (i.e. 10000 or may be more in future).

Comment: As I understand, the main problem of your question is how to make response time as short as it's possible (miliseconds). In that case, as far as i know, the best solution is to split crawling job between different computing nodes through map-reduce technique. Correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: @dorintufar. That would be my next question, as the response time is also an important thing. But for now the question is what should I do or program that would be a generic or global solution for this problem, for example as I mentioned above evey website has a different context and a different structure with different classes. My aim is to crawl the data just like Google is doing with more than 10000 sites. What will be the global solution for that, ofcourse I can't make 10000 different functions for each website.

Comment: css/xpath selectors can differ from one to another website, but some things remain unchanged (for most websites) in html structure, and that's title & head. Head have quite big probability to store some meta tags that describes something about website. I don't know, maybe it will be usefull for you :) But in fact, there's no way to predict what's the page content